# ¿Cómo hacer un trigger en SQL Server que no podrá realizar la venta si la cantidad excede de la existente?

Tags: sql-server

Quiero crear un trigger que no me deje hacer una venta porque la existencia es `0`. Estas son las tablas que tengo.

**Tabla de detalle de la factura:**

```
CREATE TABLE Empresa.tbl_detalle_fac (
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
Id_encabezado_fac INT NOT NULL,
Id_producto INT NOT NULL,
Cantidad INT NOT NULL)
```

**Tabla de existencias:**

```
CREATE TABLE Empresa.tbl_existencias (
Id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY NOT NULL,
Cod_sede INT NOT NULL,
Cantidad INT NOT NULL,
Cod_producto INT NOT NULL
)
```

Quisiera hacerlo con un trigger

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx! Qué versión de SQL Server estás usando? Has intentado algo ya? Si es así, por favor edita tu pregunta y añade la info sobre tu intento de trigger y los errores que te hayan salido

Comment: Estoy en Sql Server express

Comment: En un ejemplo tan básico como este, puedes incorporar lógica de negocios en base de datos, pero como regla general: **No se programa lógica de negocios en la base de datos**. Esa restricción no pertenece ahí.

Answer (score -2):

No hay necesidad de un trigger, podes hacerlo con transacciones:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION 
BEGIN TRY

INSERT INTO VENTA (ID, SALDO, FECHA)
VALUES(valores);

INSERT INTO DETALLEVENTA (ID, ORDEN, ARTICULO, CANTIDAD)
VALUES(valores);

UPDATE INVENTARIO
SET CANTIDAD = CANTIDAD - CANTIDAD VENDIDA 
WHERE ARTICULO ID = ARTICULO ID TABLA

COMMIT TRANSACTION 

END TRY

BEGIN CATCH

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
PRINT 'Ha ocurrido un error!'

END CATCH
```

De esta forma si no se ejecuta algunas de las instrucciones vuelve atrás todo. Por ejemplo, hace de cuenta que intentas vender un articulo sin stock, al momento de intentar ejecutar el update no va a poder, por lo que va a saltar al bloque catch y va a hacer un rollback y asi cancela todo. Por lo general, los triggers son para hacer actualizaciones en stock, no para evitar una venta. Tambien podrías poner un atributo bandera en el stock, y asi cuando se agote la ultima existencia activarla, entonces al momento de intentar hacer una venta podes poner la condición en el where. Hay muchas formas de evitar una venta por no tener stock.
También hay que tener en cuenta que esta solución solo funciona si validaste que la cantidad ingresada no sea negativa, a través de un constraint check, o también validarla del lado del cliente, etc. Esta solución tampoco te permite vender mas de lo que tenes.

Comment: Muchas gracias Franco.

Comment: Franco, por favor considera agregar la aclaratoria de que tu propuesta sólo funciona si se agrega una restricción ([Check Constraint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)) en la cantidad para que no admita valores negativos o una validación adicional en el where.

Comment: En eso tenes razón, no aclare por todas las posibles variaciones que puede tener. Ya agrego todas las consideraciones.